# Call an instance of a class dynamically

Tags: php, class

```
$inst_a = new MyClass();
$inst_b = new MyClass();
$inst_c = new MyClass();
(...)
```

now i want to call a specific function of an instance, depending on which string is provided by an post var, like this:

```
$inst_name = $_POST['inst_name'];
$inst_name->myfunct($param);
```

someone an idea?

Comment: Such a thing would be highly dangerous. e.g. consider an object for some kind of web-based disk logical volume/partition manager. `$_POST['inst_name'] = 'nuke_partitions` and bye-bye goes your drives.

Comment: i don't see such a security risk, if the myfunct is hard coded..

Comment: yes, but you'd be allowing the user to specify ANY method in your class. if they know what methods are available, they could execute code you don't want executed.

Answer (score 1):

you can instantiate a class based on a variable, your example security wise isn't very safe but here's how it's done

```
$inst_name = 'MyClass';
$inst = new $inst_name();
$inst->myfunct($param);
```

Comment: thank you roberto! This might help, but actually I was looking for something slidely else. the instance is created before the the post variable is used to call it. eg: $inst_a = new myclass(); $inst_b = new myclass; depending on which value the post var has an instance is called.